# Stopping propagation in checkbox

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I've been developing a web application using Ember 1.0 where I've have de following checkbox:

```
 <div class="col-md-2 chart-type">
       <label class="checkbox margin-left5" style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;">
              <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllSignals" id="selectAllSignals" {{action selectAllCharts "selectAllSignals" target="view"}}/> All                                   
        </label>
```

And also I've the following action:

```
 selectAllCharts : function(id){
        var isToCheck = $("#" + id).is(':checked');
        /* do something */
    },
```

When I click in the checkbox, the function it’s called and if I have a break point I see the check mark in the checkbox, the problem is when I proceed with the execution the checkbox its uncheck.

I've already put return false; to stop propagation, but with no success.

Comment: Event/context handling for checkboxes in styled labels in ember === pain.  Toggling a class on a view and using images/icon fonts instead of a straight checkbox may prevent hair loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this it's, in my point of view, a very stupid issue that ember has, I decided to lock to another way of doing this.

What I've done was put an event when the check box changes:

```
<div class="col-md-2 chart-type">
       <label class="checkbox margin-left5" style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;">
               <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllSignals" id="selectAllSignals" onchange="selectAllCharts(this)"/> All                                   
        </label>
</div>
```

and create a function for that called "selectAllCharts".

Thanks to @selva-G for your help and also to RhinoWalrus for your comment

Answer (score 0):

`Em.Checkbox` might the rightway to go

```
{{view Em.Checkbox checkedBinding="isChecked"}}
```

and

```
    checkedDidChange: function(){
   //        alert(this.get('isChecked'));
    //Some stuff here
    }.observes('isChecked')
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Selvaganesh/T25f2/1/)